# Скрипт proot дает ошибку

Tags: terminal, runtime

Написал скрипт, лежит он в приватной папке приложения.

```
#!/data/data/com.d330.veneraide/support/busybox sh

PROOT_TMP_DIR=/data/data/com.d330.veneraide/support/ /data/data/com.d330.veneraide/support/proot -r /data/data/com.d330.veneraide/debian -v -1 -p -H -0 -l -L -b /sys -b /dev -b /proc -b /data -b /mnt -b /proc/mounts:/etc/mtab -b /:/host-rootfs /data/data/com.d330.veneraide/debian/opt/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/$@
```

Он меняет директорию на файловую систему вшитого линукса с установленным JDK и передает команду джаве. отлично работает в терминале

```
cd /data/data/com.d330.veneraide/support
./java_command java -version
```

В терминал приходит ответ с информацией о версии java. Далее пытаюсь запустить скрипт из кода моего приложения:

```
runJavaCommand("java -version");

public void runJavaCommand(String command) {
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.d330.veneraide/support/java_command " + command);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    reader.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, output.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Мне приходит пустая строка. Меняю `getInputStream` на `getErrorStream` и вижу что происходила ошибка, а следом мой ответ о `java -version`:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libsigchain.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Как мне исправить эту ошибку? Она не влияет на java. Или как я могу скрыть ее, чтобы скрипт ее не отправлял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я забыл перед запуском `proot`-а выставить `LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.d330.veneraide/support/libdisableselinux.so`
ошибка пропала, но `InputStream` все равно пуст. Ответ приходит в `ErrorStream`. Обьединил их.